# how to change format of images to jpg in python?

Tags: python

I have 3 format of images I want to make all of them into `jpg` what can I do? 
`[jpg, png, jfif]` ---> `**jpg**`

Answer (score 2):

JFIF can usually be renamed JPG without any problems.

If you want to convert between PNG and JPG, you need to call PIL

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-image-convert-method/